# d3 zoom with button and double click but don't zoom with with scroll wheel

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am using [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/linssen/7352810) as a basis for zoom in my project but I would like to restrict the zoom to only the buttons and double clicking. Ideally, using the scroll wheel should just continue scrolling down the page and not zoom in on the svg when the mouse is over it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For D3 4.0, there're two ways to prevent d3 zoom from responding to wheel event.

A:

```
zoom.filter(function() { return !event.button && event.type !== 'wheel'; })
// the `!event.button` expression is from the default filter, according to
// doc for zoom.filter([filter])
```

B:

```
svg.on("wheel.zoom", null);
// according to doc for zoom(selection): Internally, the zoom behavior        
// uses selection.on to bind the necessary event listeners for zooming. 
// The listeners use the name .zoom
```

It's still possible to pan(translate) with mouse dragging.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
   //.call(zoom) //remove the zoom listener from the group.
  .append("g");
```

Next attach doublclick listener on the circle and the rectangle for zooming.

```
d3.selectAll("rect").on('dblclick', zoomClick)
d3.selectAll("circle").on('dblclick', zoomClick)
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uDXCF9v8WTa9SVCXRXzq?p=preview)